# Scikit: How to limit maximum values for prediction per sample

Tags: python, scikit-learn

is it possible to limit the maximum value for predictions per sample when using scikit? In my input data there is a column("Announcement") which is the maximum value for this particular sample, "result" in this case is the true value. How can limit the prediction between 0 - $annoucement?

Here is a very small code snippet / example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def main():
    mylist = [
    {'Id':101,'Username':"john",'Date':1475359200,'Announcement':111,'Result':50},
    {'Id':104,'Username':"john",'Date':1475359905,'Announcement':40,'Result':23},
    {'Id':222,'Username':"dave",'Date':1475399212,'Announcement':600,'Result':420},
    {'Id':301,'Username':"john",'Date':1475559256,'Announcement':300,'Result':150},
    {'Id':407,'Username':"dave",'Date':1475659277,'Announcement':10,'Result':8}
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
    df['Username'] =  pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Username'])[0] + 1).astype('category')
    y = df['Result'].values
    df = df.drop('Result', axis=1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, random_state=2)
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    print("predictions")
    print(predictions)
    print("true values")
    print(y_test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
predictions
[ 255.81049569   52.35007969]
true values
[420   8]
```

The issue is in this case the second value.

thanks in advance

Comment: No. Scikit-learn cannot do that. You need to handle that on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this natively in Scikit-Learn, but you can set the predictions to be the value in the `Announcement` column if they are greater than this value with a list comprehension:

```
predictions = [p if p < a else a for p, a in zip(predictions, X_test['Announcement'])]
```

Result:

```
predictions
[255.81049569325114, 10]
true values
[420   8]
```

Comment: i thought of doing this, but i would have preferred a solution where scikit-learn is doing this natively.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's your reason behind wanting to do it in Scikit-Learn? If you want a solution in a function, you could write your own `predict` that wraps the model's predict but limits the predictions to a value.